# Trying to get user input to move sprite in Cocos2D-X

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make user input of WASD move a sprite around in Cocos2D-X. I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correct but it gives me this error:
[expression must be a modifiable lvalue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdjj.png)

Here is my code (Note: I'm new to Cocos2D-X, so it might be a bit messy)

```
float playerX = visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x;
float playerY = visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y;
    
auto player = Sprite::create("sprites/player.png");
if (player == nullptr)
{
    problemLoading("'sprites/player.png'");
}
else
{
    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    player->setPosition(Vec2(playerX, playerY));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(player, 0);
}

    // Keyboard events
auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = [playerX, playerY](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W:
        playerY += 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_A:
        playerX -= 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_S:
        playerY -= 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_D:
        playerX += 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE:
        Director::getInstance()->end();
        break;
    }
};
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
```

There is four of the error and they all point to a different playerX/Y +=/-= 5.0f

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to assign a value to something you're not allowed to.  There are various reasons for that to happen.  Assigning to const variables, arrays, or literals for example.  I assume you are using visual studio? If you double click on the error, or look in the output tab it should point you to the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: There are four of the error and they all point to a different playerX/Y +=/-= 5.0f

Comment: Oh it looks like you are capturing the playerX and playerY by value and you are not allowed to change those in the lambda function.  You need to capture them by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mutable` specifier(which allows lambdas body to modify the objects captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions):

```
float playerX = visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x;
float playerY = visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y;
    
auto player = Sprite::create("sprites/player.png");
if (player == nullptr)
{
    problemLoading("'sprites/player.png'");
}
else
{
    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    player->setPosition(Vec2(playerX, playerY));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(player, 0);
}

    // Keyboard events
auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();

// add mutable specifier
keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = [playerX, playerY, player](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) mutable
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W:
        playerY += 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_A:
        playerX -= 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_S:
        playerY -= 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_D:
        playerX += 5.0f;
        break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE:
        Director::getInstance()->end();
        break;
    }
    
    player->setPosition(playerX, playerY);
};
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
```